# Is it possible to paste the Windows clipboard in TightVNC

Tags: vnc, tightvnc

My VPS provider gave me VNC credentials which I can use to connect to my VPS.

After TightVNC Viewer connects, I want to be able to paste my password. There are a number of buttons on the toolbar, for stuff like 'Send Ctrl-Esc', so why isn't there one for sending the contents of the clipboard ? How can this be achieved ?

The VPS is virtualised with KVM and runs Ubuntu 13.10, and I'm running the Viewer on Windows 7.

Comment: As to the reason there isn't a button, that would be best left to a TightVNC developer to answer.  If the standard Windows 7 "Paste" shortcut `CTRL+V` does not work then you are out of luck.

Comment: As Ramhound stated, Ctrl+V should work - Just be sure to connect to the VPS first, then copy the password from your Windows 7 machine, then click into the VPS and do a Ctrl+V or right-click then paste (if available)

Comment: @Ramhound, @John - Ctrl-V is not working - I'm getting a `^` when I first press it, then a `V`. I also tried `Insert`, `Shif+Insert` and right-clicking.

Comment: @MihaiRotaru - I would try a different VNC program there are several out there.  At the end of the day, if software does not support copy and paste, there isn't much you can do as a user of said software.

Comment: I know it's an old question but what does "The VPS is virtualised with KVM " mean?  A KVM doesn't make something virtualised!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, what ended up working when using TightVNC from a Windows 10 machine to a Debian machine is the process outlined in [this Arch Linux board thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=101243):

- Install `autocutsel`
- In your `~/.vnc/xstartup`, run `autocutsel -fork` before running your desktop manager.

That is, my XFCE `xstartup` would look as follows:

```
xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
autocutsel -fork
startxfce4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a text file (e.g., ~/Desktop/scratch.txt), open it, and paste the content into that first. From there, it can be copied and pasted elsewhere (e.g., terminal).

[image]